# Calling sequential Threads for Kivy app with Progress Bar

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm writing a Kivy app in which a user provides various input then clicks a button which is supposed to a call a selection of python functions which run in sequential background threads while a progress bar is updated in the GUI. I have three functions which are supposed to be called one after another, after the previous one has completed and the progress bar is at 100% the bar goes back to 0% and reports the progress of the next function etc. The problem is, if I call them in order, it looks like they're being run simultaneousy in the background with only the last one updating the progress bar. How do I setup threads to be called only after the previous one has finished?

I've tried the `join` method but it just freezes the GUI by putting the thread on the main thread.

This is the current function which is called when the button's pressed:

```
scripts_to_run = ListProperty([])

def process_data(self):
    to_run = []
    if "move_data" in self.scripts_to_run:
        self.move_data()
        to_run.append(Thread(target=self.produce_data_file))
    if "histograms" in self.scripts_to_run:
        to_run.append(Thread(target=self.histograms))
    if "log_histograms" in self.scripts_to_run:
        to_run.append(Thread(target=self.log_histograms))

    for thread in to_run:
        thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with some help from @TwfyqBhyry, I managed to put a solution together which works but there's probably a slicker way of doing it.

Since while loops don't agree with Kivy, I used what I think of as the Kivy alternative to a while loop, `Clock.schedule_interval`, to repeatedly call a function which checks if a thread is alive and calls the next thread when the previous one is no longer alive.

```
scripts_to_run = ListProperty([])

def process_data(self):
    for script in self.scripts_to_run:
        if script == "move_data":
            self.move_data()
            move_data_thread = Thread(target=self.produce_data_file)
            move_data_thread.start()
        if script == "histograms":
            histo_thread = Thread(target=self.histograms)
            if move_data_thread.is_alive():
                self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self.check_for_thread, move_data_thread, histo_thread))
            else:
                histo_thread.start()
        if script == "log_histograms":
            log_histo_thread = Thread(target=self.log_histograms)
            if move_data_thread.is_alive():
                self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self.check_for_thread, move_data_thread, log_histo_thread), 1)
            elif histo_thread.is_alive():
                self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self.check_for_thread, histo_thread, log_histo_thread), 1)
            else:
                log_histo_thread.start()
    
def check_for_thread(self, thread1, thread2, dt):
    if thread1.is_alive():
        pass
    elif thread2.is_alive():
        self.event.cancel()
    else:
        thread2.start()
```

While the method works well in this instance, you would need to add a new `if script == "function_tag"` section to the code for each process you wanted. This could potentially lead to larger and larger sections of code for each combination of previous processes and the last process. If anyone knows of a slicker, more upscalable version, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to run every next thread after the previous one finishes, so you will use conditional statement like:

```
if not thread1.is_alive():
    thread2.start()
        if not thread2.is_alive():
            thread3.start()
```

Comment: I tried this and the problem is that the conditional statements are only triggered once and that's while the first thread is still running so they aren't called again once the first thread is finished.

Comment: don't run the thread at all before the first finishes

Comment: That's what the code you posted does, it calls the first thread, then immediately after, the conditional statements are called and because the first is alive, the other threads aren't called but the conditional statements aren't called again

Comment: I've tried ```while``` loops but they don't seem to agree with Kivy

Comment: okay, that means you want when the last thread is dead the first thread run again, right?

Comment: No, I want the first thread to run, then when that's finished, I want the next thread to run and so on. I don't need any of them to run again. Each thread takes 5-10 mins to run so any is_alive called during that time will return True. I think I need it to repeatedly check for the currently running thread to finish before the next one is called to run? @TwfyqBhyry

Comment: you will simply run the first thread and at the next line make the conditional statements that i made, it should work well

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work. After the first thread is finished, the second one isn't called.

Comment: i suggest you can add a variable in the class for each thread. define these vars in the __init__ function and at the end of thread target fuction set that variable to True. and in the checking, make a while loop to check if the var is True, and if the var is True the next thread will run

Comment: I've tried this but while loops don't seem to agree with Kivy as they freeze up the GUI, in which a progress bar is supposed to be updated.

Comment: you can make the loop inside another thread